# execution order of the ready function when there are number of scripts

Tags: jquery

My page uses number of javascript files(inside the `<head>` tag, which all of them havs a $(function(){...})

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="A.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="B.js"></script>
      ...
     <script type="text/javascript" src="E.js"></script>
</head>
```

so what i would like to know, is this:

1) does the ready function of script A ($(function(){....}) will wait until all the rest of the scripts loaded(A till E)?

2) does the order of all ready functions  **necessity** executed in the order of the files inside the `<head>` tag ( **e.g** -first ready function of A....and last- ready function of E)?

the reason i am asking all of this, is because there is some dependences between the scripts. so that ready function of B need to be executed only after the ready function of A **done**, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document.ready` functions will be executed in the order that the scripts are loaded.  You can easily test this by putting `console.log("a")` in `a.js`, `console.log("b")` in `b.js` etc. and watch the console when you load the page.

They will all fire, one after the other, when the DOM is loaded, which does include the scripts.  So all scripts in the DOM will be loaded by the time `document.ready` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

1.)`document.ready` will not wait for other files to download .It only waits for `DOM` to load.

2.)It fires sequentially based on the order you put your scripts.